# Zurb Foundation 5, modernizr not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, asset-pipeline, zurb-foundation, assets

I get this when using Foundation 5.0.2.0 in production mode.

On Rails, Unicorn, NginX & Ubuntu.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://mydomain.com/javascripts/vendor/modernizr.js"
```

Comment: I assume `...nu` is your obfuscated domain name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update 3/13/14**

I don't have this problem on heroku with [foundation-rails-5.1.1.0](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails).  Adding `javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr"` in the head works.  I could remove the modernizr I copied to the vendor directory and remove the extra line in app.js

---

I had the same problem on heroku, the app would crash because it couldn't find modernizr.js.  Here's how I fixed it:

- Copy modernizr.js from foundation (wherever you installed it with bundler) into *vendor/assets/javascripts/*.
- Add `//= require modernizr` below `//= require_tree .` on application.js.
- Remove `javascript_include_tag "vendor/moderizr"` from application.html

Comment: This solves the issue but the error still appear even though I removed the javascript_include_tag. But the modernizr is activated. But it should be resolved correctly. But until then this is the way to go.

Comment: I think I ran into a problem doing things this way because foundation-rails currently calls the application.js file from the body and not the head of application.html and I had other scripts which only worked when placed in the head and which seemed to pre require modernizr.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error as you and I did this to fix it:

In `config/environments/production.rb`, set this:

```
# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: This works but is bad practice. You should find out _why_ the asset was not precompiled and if possible make sure that it _does_ get precompiled. See my answer for a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the gem you're using for Foundation. [This commit from five days ago may help you](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/commit/18007b52bfe813b990e331b3f702a9fc37671e99) since it claims to add a missing `modernizr.js` file.

Comment: This is indeed part of the problem. However, after successfully updating, it's still not working. I even copied the custom.modernizr.js file from the bower_componenets/foundation/js/vendor directory into the rails vendor/assetsjavascripts directory. Still no love. Did you have to do anything else to get it working?

Comment: I haven't tried your configuration. I just spotted a commit in the Foundation repository which suggested a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the version of the foundation-rails gem you are using. In fact even the latest version currently available (5.0.3.1) has this problem. There is a pull request which claims to fix this: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/pull/71 but another option for now is to update your gem to 5.0.3.1 and add this line to your production.rb file:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/modernizr.js )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the manual instructions from zurb here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/applications.html

Which specifiy that the modernizr script be included inside the head tag.  I ran into this issue and then fixed it using the following code in layouts/application.rb:

```
%head

  %title= title
  = stylesheet_link_tag    "application"
  = javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr"
  = csrf_meta_tags
  = favicon_link_tag
  = yield(:head)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **foundation-rails (5.2.2.0)** and I solved it by just adding:

> //= require modernizr

below

> //= require_tree .

in **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**