# foundation-rails, vendor/modernirz isn't precompiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation

I have the same kind of issue as here : 
[Zurb Foundation 5, modernizr not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224896/zurb-foundation-5-modernizr-not-found)

I tried to fix this problem by testing multiple answers from here and from github's related threads, but nothing seems to work.

I'm using `"rails", "3.2.15"` and `foundation-rails", "5.1.1.0"`

I receive a 500 error, here is what I found in my production's log file:

```
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6.1ms

ActionView::Template::Error (vendor/modernizr.js isn't precompiled):
    8: 
    9:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
    10:   <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    11:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    12: </head>
    13: 
    14: <body id="bg">
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in     `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4555789472361352826_33758840'
```

This is very strange because early in my log file, a line tell me that modernizr is correctly compiled.

```
....
Compiled application.css  (14023ms)  (pid 4212)
Compiled vendor/modernizr.js  (3ms)  (pid 4212)
Compiled active_admin/print.css  (307ms)  (pid 4212)
...
```

Here is an extract of my production's environment file:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
config.cache_store = :memory_store
config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/modernizr.js )
```

Thanks in advance for your advice!

PS: everytime I use these commands

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Ok guys, I successfully debugged myself thanks to apache2 and passenger.
My ruby version wasn't the one that I used for my project...
It was really hard to guess since I wasn't aware that passenger need to restart each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

In application.rb

Then :

I advise you to include the CSS / Less / Js by yourself, this avoid to be dependent on a gem.

You can try something like this : http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application/

Pros : You're not dependent on a Gem, for example Foundation update to version from 4 to 5, you just have to update your CSS / LESS / JS files, and you don't have to wait for the gem to be updated.

Cons : The gem give you some helpers that save you a lot of time.

To get those helpers working with your project, you can just copy / paste the helpers from Bootstrap-Gems or Foundation-Gems in your project.